# d3.js difficulty rendering bar chart code taken from bl.ocks sample

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to run [This Code](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3310560) in Fiddle but struggling to render anything. I've replaced the datasource with an object array within the script but not sure if I'm referencing it correctly.  Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/9yu0wenk/15/)

Any ideas?

```
d3.tsv(letters, type, function(error,letters) {
  x.domain(letters.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(letters, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, the issue is the call to `d3.tsv` as you have replaced the data source in your code with the `letters` variable.

To get this to work, I commented out the call to d3.tsv so the x.domain call is the next statement in the script after the variable is declared, then removed the corresponding brackets further down (lines 53/54).  See working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mpxt79fh/